# JUnit passing parameters between class

Tags: java, junit4

I have a scenario as follows that I'm not sure from where to start,

File name should be passed as an argument param when running the jar file

say for example I want to test a set of data from external file and I have a super class (Test Suite) that have number one and number two

and there are two test classes that should extend this class and perform the tests.

I'm currently new to JUnit so I'm lacking many concepts and need someone's help.

I have class CoreManager which executes the main

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("Import"))
        {
       accountInfo = new ArrayList<>();
       int ImportIndex = Arrays.asList(args).indexOf("Import");
       String fileName = args[ImportIndex+1];
       if (fileName.contains("xml"))
       {
           ParseXML parseXML = new ParseXML();
           accountInfo = parseXML.ParseAccounts(fileName);

           Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(LoginTestSuite.class);

           for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
               System.out.println(failure.toString());
           }

           System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
       }
   }
}
```

And Suite Class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

 @Suite.SuiteClasses({
    Login.class,
    SignUp.class
```

})

```
public class LoginTestSuite {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static ArrayList<AccountInfo> Account;
public static int SecondsToWait;

public LoginTestSuite(WebDriver driver,ArrayList<AccountInfo> Account,int 
secondsToWait)
{
this.Account = Account;
this.SecondsToWait = secondsToWait;
this.driver = driver;
}
```

}

And Test Class

public class Login {

```
private static WebDriver driver;
private static ArrayList<AccountInfo> Account;
private static int SecondsToWait;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName());



@BeforeClass
public void init(){
    this.driver = LoginTestSuite.driver;
    this.Account = LoginTestSuite.Account;
    this.SecondsToWait = LoginTestSuite.SecondsToWait;
}

@Before
public void Setup(){

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(SecondsToWait, 
     TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(SecondsToWait, 
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@After
public void TearDown(){
    driver.quit();
}



@Test
public void TestUserLogin() throws Exception
{
    // Logic

}
```

Comment: You should post some code to *illustrate*

Comment: show  some code plz

Comment: Do it and then ask concrete question

Comment: @RC. I've added code for you to check :)

Comment: All your code seems to be test code - where is the production code you are testing?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster I'm stuck with main function returning Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor. I'm unable to initialize the test classes from outside. I want to do it from main class which is CoreManager file.

Comment: Normally you would not use a main method to start tests, but write annotated test classes (in a separate source directory like 'src/test/java') that are invoked by your build automatically.

Comment: It is not clear what your production code should be doing, nor what you are trying to accomplish with your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks muddled and contains several poor quality constructs. Most importantly, I don't see a distinction between test code and production code. Which is which?

This could be production code:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
           AccountReader accountReader = new AccountReader();  
           List<AccountInfo> accounts = accountReader.read(args); 
           // maybe do something with those accounts?                         
    }
}

public class AccountReader {

    private ParseXML parseXML;

    public AccountReader() {
         this.parseXML = new ParseXML();
    }

    // extra constructor to allow dependency injection from test
    protected AccountReader(ParseXML parseXML) {
         this.parseXML = parseXML;
    }

    public List<AccountInfo> read(String[] args) {          
           return parseXML.ParseAccounts(getFileName(args));          
    }

    private String getFileName(String[] args) {
        List<String> arguments = Arrays.asList(args);          
        int importIndex = arguments.indexOf("Import");    
        if (importIndex < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing Import argument");
        }        
        int fileNameIndex = importIndex + 1;
        if (fileNameIndex >= arguments.size()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing fileName argument");
        }
        String fileName = args[fileNameIndex];
        if (!fileName.endsWith(".xml")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can only import XML files");
        } 
        return fileName;  
    }

}
```

And this could be a test for it:

```
public AccountReaderTest {

    private AccountReader instance;
    @Mock // creates a mock instance which we can give desired behavior
    private ParseXML parseXML;
    @Mock
    List<AccountInfo> accounts;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        instance = new AccountReader(parseXML);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHappy() {        
        // SETUP
        String fileName = "test.xml";
        // specify desired behavior of mock ParseXML instance
        when(parseXML.ParseAccounts(fileName).thenReturn(accounts);

        // CALL 
        List<AccountInfo> result = instance.read(new String[] { "Import", fileName });

        // VERIFY
        assertEquals(accounts, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testMissingImport() {        
         instance.read(new String[] { "notImport" });
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testMissingFileName() {        
         instance.read(new String[] { "Import" });
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testNotXml() {        
         instance.read(new String[] { "Import", "test.properties"});
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't yet optimized anything. I want to achieve the following

1- Have a function that acts as "main" to be able to parse the args passed to  java jar file after being published
2- the arguments should contain which file to parse and pass the parsed file to the test suite
3- the test suite will then run ALL the test cases linked to it.